# Why is my radio button not changing visually? The change fires but the visual appearance does not change

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

Problem: Radio buttons fire change but do not change visual appearance.

I have a simple form that lets you post a status update or new blog post. All form fields are hidden on page load, except for the textarea. When you click in the textarea, more of the form appears, including two radio buttons that let you choose between a status update or a blog post. The difference between the two is that the blog post gets an additional field called Post Title which appears if you click the standard radio button. The scenario is set up in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XH7eP/1/

So here's the problem. You'll notice if you click the "Standard" post format, the Post Title field *does* appear as expected. The change is firing, but the radio button has not changed its visual appearance. You can click either one to show/hide the post title field, but the visual appearance never changes.

I am stumped. Any insights would be much appreciated. Here's the code from the fiddle.

```
<form id="new_post_form" name="status_update" method="post" action="">
<p>Update your status</p>
<div class="upper">
    <div class="new_post_form_hiding_fields hide">
        <label>Post Format: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="new_post_format" id="status-post-format" class="post-format-radio" value="status" checked="checked" /> <label>status</label>
        <input type="radio" name="new_post_format" id="standard-post-format" class="post-format-radio" value="standard" /> <label>standard</label>
        <div class="standard_post_format_fields hide">
            <label>Post Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="new_post_title" name="title" value="" tabindex="3" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<textarea name="post_content" id="new_post_content" tabindex="2" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 47px;"></textarea>
<div class="new_post_form_hiding_fields hide">
    <input type="submit" id="new_post_submit" value="submit" tabindex="6" />
</div>
</form>
```

jQuery next

```
$('#new_post_form').click(function(e) {
$('.new_post_form_hiding_fields').slideDown();
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
$(document).click(function() {
if( $('.new_post_form_hiding_fields' ).is(":visible") ) {
    $('.new_post_form_hiding_fields').slideUp();
}
});

$('.post-format-radio').click(function() {
if( $('#standard-post-format').prop('checked') ) {
    $('.standard_post_format_fields').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.standard_post_format_fields').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the stopPropagation return false means you want to stop any click to execute, after stop propagation its not need to return anything method will take care of preventing event from bubbling up.

```
 $('#new_post_form').click(function(e) {
$('.new_post_form_hiding_fields').slideDown();
e.stopPropagation(); });
```

[jsfiddle.net/XH7eP/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/XH7eP/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much @Neha. I'm still too new to jQuery to even see things like that :-/  Fixed.